# Run a script during shutdown/termination of an aws instance

Tags: linux, debian, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, systemd

I need to execute a script during shutdown/termination of an AWS instance(debian). I added my script to the /etc/init.d/myscript and a symlink to /etc/rc0.d/K01myscript however I noticed that when I terminate the instance I don't see that my script is executed. Any idea?

Comment: How do you know it's not being executed? Are there any local `~` references, or programs that are expected to be in the path? May have to explicitly state the location of whatever needs to run.

Comment: I'll explain my use case. I'm using Sensu for monitoring and my app is running under an ASG. So I use systemd for the sensu client service.  When an instance is boot up, it will automatically connected to the Sensu master server. What I need is when the instance goes down, it needs to deregister from the Sensu master server. I had tried the script manually and it's working fine as expected. What I want is to execute this script during the shutdown process.

Answer (score 2):

> So I use **systemd** for the sensu client service

If this is indeed so, then you do **not** use init scripts at all. All you need to do is to add the two following lines to your systemd service:

```
 RemainAfterExit=yes
 ExecStop=/path/to/executable/script
```

The first option instructs systemd to treat the service as a daemon, *i.e.* to treat it as running even though all processes have died already; the second instruction points systemd to the cleanup script, which you will have to provide.